# rem units on Asian browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-size, responsive, asianfonts

I've developed a site, in English, of a global company that is also visited from Asian places like Japan, China etc.
For responsive reasons I set most of the units in the site in REM. also for height, width, padding etc.

The font-size is set correctly, but all the other properties - doesn't. for example I have a div with the property: padding-left: 43rem; when my browser is in English - the div has padding of 43px (the html's font-size is 1px). When my browser is in Japanese (Chrome) - the div has padding-left of 430px.
Another example: The header tag has height: 78rem. In an English browser it is 78px height, but in the Japanese browser - 780px.

I saw that the sizes don't change when I change the font-size of the  tag. the header has the same height - 780px - when the html has font-size 1px, 2px or 10px.

Also - any element with font-size in rem - the font-size is set correctly also in Japanese browser. That is the only property that is set correctly with rem units.

Can anyone help?
Thanks!

--EDIT

The site: http://amimon.com.

The browser is chrome. I set it's language to Japanese. I understood from our customer that the same problem happens in Chines too.

I also tried to set the html's font-size out of the @media, but with any change...

Thanks all of you for helping (or for trying to help...)

Comment: What exactly does "browser is in Japanese" mean? Are you switching the language setting within the browser somewhere? Are you installing a different language version? Are you using a completely different computer with a Japanese operating system?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? Or if that isn't possible, can you link to the website? There can be many things that go wrong, and without seeing the site itself, all you will get is guesswork.

Comment: One such guess is that if you have a minimum font size if your browser's settings, for instance 10px, then `html {font-size:1px}` will actually result in the font size being 10px. And some browsers can set different minimum font sizes for different languages.